# Can Mosques in the UAE be Visited by Non-Muslims?

Tags: dubai, uae, abu-dhabi, islam, mosques

**Which mosques can be visited by non-Muslims in Abu Dhabi and Dubai?**

Are foreigners and non-Muslims restricted to certain times? What about certain dates?

Are the different restrictions for visiting the exterior, grounds and interior?

Comment: I believe so. Weren't the **Kartrashians** in the news for showing skin in a mosque in the UAE ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the Dubai authorities, the Jumeirah Mosque is "the only mosque in Dubai which is open to the public and dedicated to receiving non-Muslim guests." (At least insofar as going inside is concerned, I can't speak to the grounds, and you can certainly see mosques from the outside around the city.)

They [operate a tour](http://www.cultures.ae/index.php/ouractivities/jumeirah-mosque-visit) most days:

> The Sheikh Mohammed Centre for Cultural Understanding hosts visits of
>   the Grand Jumeirah Mosque 6 days a week Saturday through Thursday at
>   10:00am. You do not need a reservation to attend this visit, but you
>   must arrive at the main entrance to the Jumeirah Mosque by
>   approximately 9.45am. Each tour lasts approximately 75 minutes. The
>   tour cost 20 AED per person including water, dates, Arabic coffee,
>   tea, and traditional pastries. Children under 12 are free.  Parties of
>   10 or more should contact the SMCCU prior to your visit.
>
> Modest dress is preferred, however traditional attire can be borrowed
>   from the Mosque.

If you want even more, the page goes on to indicate that it is possible to arrange a private visit of the Jumeirah Mosque, along with several other mosques, if you contact them in advance.

Comment: Any similar information about Abu Dhabi?

Comment: @Itai Sorry I've never been to Abu Dhabi. A quick Google search shows the [Grand Mosque](http://www.szgmc.ae/en/mosque-opening-hours) has visiting hours and "walk-in" tours. I'm not seeing anything that says the tour is only open to Muslims, and it appears they'd welcome any interested visitors (who comply with their dress code). But that's all I really know.

Comment: Are there restrictions on times or day of entry?

Comment: @Itai the linked page lists the days and times of the tour.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I missed that you even quoted it, sorry. Having a case of planning stress I suppose :(

Comment: No worries. Have a great trip!